# line of sources for differential equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

It is well known that for representation of point source with some intensity $q(t)$ in some PDE we use delta-function $\delta({\bf r} - {\bf r}')$. If problem 
requires usage of line of sources which is parallel to x-axis we use Heaviside step
function: $\delta(z-z_0)\delta(y-y_0)[\theta(x-x_2) - \theta(x-x_1)]$.

But how to represent line of sources if it is not parallel to neither x-axis nor y-axis (if it lies along some line with equation $y=kx$, $k\neq 0$)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've found the solution:

Let's express the "line of sources" as superposition of $\delta$-functions.
To obtain it we use parametrization of the line: $x = x(p), y = y(p)$, where $p \in [0; L]$ (L -- is length of the line). So we can write down the expression:
$$
\int_0^L \delta(x - x(p))\delta(y-y(p))q(x(p), y(p), t)\,dp
$$

Also it is clear that this expression is valid for any line (not only for a straight one).

But, actually, I am not quite sure in this solution...